# Populate withJSON data formArray Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to edit a data but I don't know how can I popule the form again with the json response from my API

In my response i get my json

```
project: {
    "id": 1,
    "customer": "Jhonathan",
    "steps": "{\"id\":1,\"paso\":\"Paso 1\",\"accion\":\"accion 1\",\"punto_critico\":\"punto critico 1\",\"razon\":\"razon 1\",\"fichero\":\"fileImage",\"namefile\":\"3.jpg\"}",
    "epp": "{\"zapatos\":\"zapatos\",\"guantes\":\"guantes\",\"mandil\":\"mandil\",\"lentes\":\"lentes\",\"faja\":\"faja\",\"chaleco\":\"chaleco\",\"tapones\":\"tapones\",\"mascarilla\":\"mascarilla\",\"otro\":\"\"}",
    "turns": "[\"2 Turno\"]",
    "created_at": "2021-01-13T15:20:49.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-01-15T02:20:33.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
}
```

I've my form in this way

```
editProject = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [1],
  customer: [''],
  steps: this.formBuilder.array([this.newStep]),
  epp: new FormGroup({
    zapatos: new FormControl(''),
    guantes: new FormControl(''),
    mandil: new FormControl(''),
    lentes: new FormControl(''),
    faja: new FormControl(''),
    chaleco: new FormControl(''),
    tapones: new FormControl(''),
    mascarilla: new FormControl(''),
    otro: new FormControl(''),
  }),
  turns: [[]],
})
```

the form that i create the step array is with this

```
    getNewId() {
    this.currentStepId += 1;
    return this.currentStepId;
  }

  get newStep(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.getNewId()],
      paso: ['Paso ' + this.currentStepId],
      accion: [''],
      punto_critico: [''],
      razon: [''],
      fichero: ['']
    })
  }

  get steps(): FormArray {
    return this.editProject.get('steps') as FormArray
  }

  Addsteps() {
    this.steps.push(this.newStep);
  }
```

Is my firts time trying to do this. I tray making like this but I think that i got a infinit loop because my app never stop charging and it crash

```
for(let line = 0; line < response.project.steps.length; line++){
   const linesFormArray = this.editProject.get('steps') as FormArray;
   linesFormArray.push(this.newStep);
}
```

hope someone can help me

Comment: I think you have an infinite loop with Angular's life cycle and `newStep`. You could try to use a variable. If this solves your problem you have to find a different approach.

Comment: @ThomasSablik what do you mean with use a variable? I mean where?

Comment: Instead of the getter function `get newStep()` use a variable `newStep` and set it once. If this solves your infinite loop you can think about a solution.

Comment: I change some things on the component and I got new errors, let me edit my question